# HTML table Aligning and format

Tags: html, jsp

I have three columns in a table. 1st and 3rd column have plenty of rows. 2nd column has only row, but i want this row to be located in middle of table. I am not getting desired result.

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="Usrs">
                <select name="z" id="z" size="25" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px">
                    <option>abc</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">
            Move
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="Usrs">
                <select name="z" id="z" size="25" multiple="multiple" style="width: 200px">
                    <option>abc</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Attached the image also. Help me where am I going wrong

[image: .]

Comment: This code works for me (FF 7.0.1)

Comment: "move" should go to centre of 2nd column, as shown by arrow

Comment: Yes, this is what I have. Move in the middle of 2nd column

Comment: Ok. Which version of browser are you using?

Comment: I'm working with FF 8.0 and IE8.0 in both it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "vertical-align:" instead of "valign:"

```
style="vertical-align: middle"
```

http://www.css4you.de/Texteigenschaften/vertical-align.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a `div` or `span` tag, and mention the `width` and `height` in it.